# jquery .000000001 converts to 1e-9 want to avoid it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid, telerik

I am working on telerik mvc grid. Whenever I enter .0000000001 it displays in grid like 1e-9
and other numbers to their corresponding exponential form. Though the exponential form is correct representation of the corresponding number but I want to avoid the exponential form. Is there any workaround.

Comment: are you aware that "jquery" is **not** a programming language?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.toFixed` .
Example :

```
var original_num ;
original_num = 0.0000000001;
result = original_num.toFixed(10);
```